# Logging home natural gas usage using rrdtool

Tags: graph, rrdtool, rrd

I'm pulling home gas usage from my meter at home, and trying to save it to an RRD database, and pulling from there to create a graph, using rrdtool.

I've been doing this for different data sources using GAUGE db types, those are all updating/graphing fine. for some reason I don't seem to be able to get things running using a COUNTER type data source.

Here's what I've been using.

```sh
rrdtool create db/gas.rrd --step 300 \
      DS:gas_in:COUNTER:600:0:U  \
      RRA:AVERAGE:0.8:1:300    \
      RRA:AVERAGE:0.8:12:200   \
      RRA:MAX:0.8:1:300        \
      RRA:MAX:0.8:12:200
```

These are the rrdtool update statements:

```
rrdtool update db/gas.rrd N:0
rrdtool update db/gas.rrd N:52
rrdtool update db/gas.rrd N:64
rrdtool update db/gas.rrd N:458
etc.
```

Create graph

```
rrdtool graph \
-E -R light \
-t "Gas" \
-v "cm^3" \
gas.png \
--start 21600  \
DEF:gas=db/gas.rrd:gas_in:AVERAGE \
LINE1:gas#99ff00:"Gas (cm^3)\t" \
GPRINT:gas:LAST:"last %3.0lf%s" \
GPRINT:gas:AVERAGE:"avg. %3.0lf%s\n"
```

Example of resulting image:

[image]

Output from rrdtool fetch db/gas.rrd MAX -e1564217220 -s$((1564217220-21600))

```
--%<--
1564217100: -nan
1564217400: -nan
--%<--
```

If I run update whith the debug option:

```
$ rrdtool updatev /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:900
return_value = 0
[1564131900]RRA[AVERAGE][1]DS[gas_in] = NaN
[1564132500]RRA[AVERAGE][1]DS[gas_in] = NaN
[1564132800]RRA[AVERAGE][1]DS[gas_in] = NaN
----%<--- (more NaN's)
```

Running this a second time only returns

```
return_value = 0
```

(not sure what that signifies, probably 'not allowed because same value?')

It looks like the data isn't making it into the RRD. What am I doing wrong? (I'm afraid the answer will include something about 'rate').

[update] 
I've been logging some actual data to a separate file:

```
20190811_165002 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_165502 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_170003 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_170504 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_171004 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_171505 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_172005 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_172506 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_173007 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_173507 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_174008 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_174508 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_175009 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_175510 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_180010 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5284
20190811_180511 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_181002 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_181502 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_182003 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_182503 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_183004 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_183505 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_184005 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_184506 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_185006 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_185507 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_190008 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_190508 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_191009 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_191509 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_192010 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_192511 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_193011 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_193502 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_194002 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_194503 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_195004 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_195504 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_200005 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5321
20190811_200505 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5710
20190811_201006 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5710
20190811_201507 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5710
20190811_202007 /usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/arne/scripts/rrd/db/gas.rrd N:5710
```

The graph is still not showing any data (only nan's). The data's updating every hour, so I should probably change my rrd create scheme. But still, this data should've been captured, right?

Comment: The return value of 0 means all is OK; the lack of RRA output on the second attempt just means that no RRAs were updated (unsurprisingly, since you'd already sent a sample for that time window).  Note that, if you're using type COUNTER, you'll need to have at least 3 updates, approx 5min apart, before you'll see any data in the RRA because COUNTER is a diff between two full time windows.

Comment: Changed 'step' to 3600 and whatever the '600' signifies to '7200'. Seems to be working now.

Comment: The '600' in the DS definition is the heartbeat.  You must receive an update at least this often else the DS becomes unknown.  Usually, this is set to 2x the step.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify how much time you have waited between the updates in your sample data, but I suspect it is too short.

Since the DS is of type COUNTER, you need to have two complete time windows before the RRA can update with a delta-per-sec values.  Since your updates are unlikely to be exactly on a window boundary, this means you'll need 3 samples.  Since your step is 300, this means you'll need a 5min delay between each sample.

Your data are monotonically increasing, so it appears suitable for a COUNTER, though the rate per second will be very small.

Make sure you have a delay when entering your sample data:

```
rrdtool updatev db/gas.rrd N:0
sleep 300
rrdtool updatev db/gas.rrd N:52
sleep 300
rrdtool updatev db/gas.rrd N:64
sleep 300
rrdtool updatev db/gas.rrd N:458
```

I would expect this to start to show some values in the RRA on the *third* update, and from then on.

Note that you have used a high XFF in your RRA definition, so your lower granularity RRAs will be more likely to conceal missing data.

Comment: See question body for additional data.